# Regular expression for checking extra space(more than one) in middle of words

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I'm using `regex=/^(\w+\s?)*\s*$/`, it's working fine for extra space, but failing for special characters.

Expectation:

1. `regex.test('abcd     ghh')`  => `false`
2. `regex.test('abcd*')` => `true`

Comment: Your regex [matches neither of these strings](https://regex101.com/r/wr3eVx/1). It seems you are using the regex with `g` modifier. Please make sure you have no `g` flag. Also, what are you trying to achieve? It is not clear from the question/title.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the last regex pattern of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758798/how-to-search-for-occurrences-of-more-than-one-space-between-words-in-a-line/3758841).

`[^\s]([ ]{2,})[^\s]`